# Corrupted installer cache | Manually repair Office without losing user settings

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008, microsoft-office-2010, repair, terminal-services

**Problem**

On a Windows 2008 Terminal Server no patches can be installed for Office 2010. The `installer cache` seems to be corrupted.

**Question**

Is there a way to `manually repair` the office 2010 installation without losing the user settings? After that repair the installation must be updateable again.

**More information**

On a Windows 2008 Terminal Server no patches can be installed for Office 2010. When trying to install a patch (or service pack) we get the message that the affiliated product is not present. Even an offline updater (wsusoffline) doesn’t recognize an Office 2010.

**The probable cause**

This behavior seems to be caused by running a patch cleaner in the past. This has probably corrupted the installer cache on the system.

**What was tried so far**

- Manually install patches and service pack
- Fixing other known installation problems (uninstalling / reinstalling the software)
- Trying to run automatic repair for the Office 2010
- setup.exe /repair
  […]

Comment: Any repair steps you take won't affect users' settings since those are stored in their personal profile folders. Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling Office?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator No haven't tried. We have only one shot. Are you sure that settings like mail account settings in outlook will work after uninstall / reinstall?

Comment: Yup. All the user preferences and settings are either in users' appdata folder or user Registry hives. None of that will be removed even if you uninstall Office. Of course, a system backup is always recommended when making big changes.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Worked fine, thanks. I would accept this as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there a way to manually repair the office 2010 installation without losing the user settings?....What was tried so far....Trying to run automatic repair for the Office 2010*

You're at the point that you need to uninstall and then reinstall Office.  You can do this *without* putting any of your users' settings or data at risk. All user-specific Office data is saved either in the user's AppData folder structure, or their personal HKCU Registry hive.  Neither of these locations are affected by an Office uninstall or install operation.

If a normal Control Panel uninstall doesn't work, two other options are available:

1. Use Microsoft's Office 2010 Uninstall Easy Fix tool, available [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8#OfficeVersion=2010).
2. Manually uninstall Office following [these directions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manually-uninstall-office-4e2904ea-25c8-4544-99ee-17696bb3027b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#officeversion=2010).  Normally I would quote such directions directly in the answer, however it involves nearly 70 steps and isn't the primary topic of the original question.

Of course, whenever making major changes to a system (especially a server) a backup is required.